# Data format not valid for google visualization

Tags: python, json, google-visualization

I am trying to visualize some data as a simple bar graph. I am getting that data in python and sending it over to the client side. This is the python code for it -

```
query_string = 'SELECT state, count(*) FROM [{0}] GROUP by state;'.format(_DATABASE_NAME)
births = self.run_query(query_string, filename='data/states.json')
outcome = []
for row in births:
   age = row['mother_age']
   times = row['f0_']
   ip = {'age': int(age), 'times': int(times)}
   outcome = outcome + [ip]
outcome.insert(0, ('Age', 'No of occurunces'))
logging.info(json.encode(outcome))
```

And this is what I get to see in the log files -

```
[["Age","No of occurunces"],{"age":31,"times":6170247},{"age":30,"times":6876756},{"age":26,"times":8271245},..........]
```

This is the index.html file -

```
html>
<head>
  <script type='text/javascript' src='https://www.google.com/jsapi'></script>
  <script type='text/javascript'>
   google.load('visualization', '1', {'packages': ['geochart']});
   google.setOnLoadCallback(drawMap);

    function drawMap() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{times|safe}});

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:600, height:400,
            vAxis: {title: "Year"},
            hAxis: {title: "Cups"}}
      );
}

  </script>
</head>

<body>
  <div id='map_canvas'></div>

</body>

</html>
```

It gives me an error saying - 
Uncaught Error: Invalid row type for row 0 
lda
Tp
drawMap on line 10 (ie this line -  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable({{times|safe}});)

I tried this out on the google visualization playground and it works just fine. Here is that code -

```
function drawVisualization() {
  // Create and populate the data table.
  var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([
    ['Year', 'Austria'],
    ['2003',  1336060],
    ['2004',  1538156],
    ['2005',  1576579],
    ['2006',  1600652],
    ['2007',  1968113],
    ['2008',  1901067]
  ]);

  // Create and draw the visualization.
  new google.visualization.BarChart(document.getElementById('visualization')).
      draw(data,
           {title:"Yearly Coffee Consumption by Country",
            width:600, height:400,
            vAxis: {title: "Year"},
            hAxis: {title: "Cups"}}
      );
}
​
```

What is wrong in my code?

Comment: You have to prepare an array of arrays without property names. This line `ip = {'age': int(age), 'times': int(times)}` should be changed.

Comment: @AntoJurković - I tried doing that. The problem still persists. Just to be doubly sure, I did this -
ip = [int(age), int(times)]

Comment: What does your code output when you use `ip = [int(age), int(times)]`?